# What exactly is a "mighty man of valor"?

Tags: hebrew, judges

In [Judges 6:12](https://biblehub.com/judges/6-12.htm), the Messenger of the LORD spoke over Gideon calling him a "mighty man of valor". In Hebrew, the phrase is "[Geebor](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/1368.htm) [He'Chayeel](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/2428.htm)":Mighty/Powerful/Prevailer of Value/Worth/Wealth/Force/Power.  What exactly does the name/phrase "mighty man of valor" mean and what would one who possess those qualities look like in this day and age?

Comment: "Gibor-Hechayil" גִּבּ֥וֹר הֶחָֽיִל simply means 'Valiant'-'Warrior'. * When Gideon גִּדְעוֹן֙ begins a spiritual battle to believe in monotheism and worship only YHVH.

Comment: @חִידָה hi, what do you mean by *spiritual battle*, could you give me a definition?

Comment: Gideon - was a good son that honored his father who worshipped Baal. Gideon was afraid to destroy his father's household Baal idol to honor YHVH. [Judges 6:25-30]

Comment: @חִידָה Does חָֽיִל and גִּבּ֥וֹר have only one meaning?

Answer (score 1):

NIV translate it as "mighty warrior". But if Gideon only had bravery and strength, he only worth the title of warrior. The Lord called him "mighty" because he had something more.

**Judicious**

> In Judges 6:11-18, Gideon had a dialogue with someone appeared to have
> authority. He proposed an unusual request, suggested bringing him an
> offering but asked the person to stay. He took hours to prepare the
> meat and bread. So maybe he thought, a stranger would not wait for
> him. He returned and saw the angel awaited for him, giving him the
> sign, and he exclaimed, "Alas, Sovereign Lord! I have seen the angel
> of the Lord face to face!” (Judges 6:22). Immediately he knew he had offended the Lord but the Lord said, “Peace! Do not be afraid. You are not going to die.” (Judges 6:23)

**Obedience**

> In Judges 6:25-27. The Lord told Gideon to tear down his father altar
> to Baal and cut down the Asherah pole. Gideon did it the same night
> right away, avoid the daytime that might have resistance from his
> family and the townspeople.

**Assertion**

> Judges 6:36-40 was an incredible event. He asked for a sign once and
> he lived. Now he asked again for another sign, and another, to confirm
> he was the chosen one. The Lord must have seen quality in him to grant
> Gideon the sign. "Assertion" may not be the right word and anyone is
> welcome to correct it.

**Fearless**

> Judges 7 recorded the battle with Midian. Gideon raised 32000 men,
> which the Lord cut it down to 300, against an army of Midian, Amalek
> and all the other eastern peoples that described as "thick as
> locusts". Gideon might still have a little doubt, but the Lord gave
> another sign, and since then, he was fearless moving on.

In our modern day, do we have anyone like Gideon? Spiritually we are mighty warrior against Satan. For we are

1. Judicious to chose righteousness
2. Obedient to our Lord Jesus
3. Assertive of our salvation
4. Fearless of death to glorify Him

Comment: I appreciate your answer, as it brings a different perspective that I have yet to come across. Thank you.